# Algorithm to process all files and folders across multiple runs

Tags: google-apps-script

I note the new Docslist [Token](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_token) and `get*ForPaging()` options available now but I am still struggling with an algorithm to process "all files and folders" for arbitrarily large file/folder trees.

Assume a Google Drive based web file system with *n* files and folders. It will take multiple runs of 6 minutes to get through with a Google Apps Script. Nightly I need to process all files older than 30 days in trees of subfolders beneath a starting folder. I need to process each file once only (but my functions are idempotent so I don't mind if I run against files again).

I have my recursive algo working but the thing that I am missing is a way to have a placeholder so that I don't have to start at the top of the folder tree each time I invoke the script. In six minutes I get through only a few hundred folders and a few thousand files.

My question is what index can I store and how do I start where I left off the next time through?

I have thought about storing Tokens or the last completed folder path "/mytop/sub4/subsub47/" but how would that help me on another invocation? If I started there it would falsely just work down the tree from there and miss siblings and ancestor folders.

I have thought about the "find" methods and using a "before:2012/10..." style search but there's no way to limit that to files in my tree (only a single folder).

I am not pasting my code as it's just standard recursive getFolders/getFiles and not actually relevant to the core of the question.

Comment: Hi, when you say *"I need to process all files older than 30 days in trees of subfolders beneath a starting folder"* what do you mean by "process" ? do you need to move the files or ??

Comment: No, I don't need to move them or rename them. I actually need to change the owner (which I do with a docslist api wrapped call) but for the purpose of the question it's a multipurpose need - for example, I may need to just count the files or log their names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create an array of the folders that I have to work on and save it all for a future run.
Since you said it's no problem to work on some files/folders repeatedly, you don't even need to put a fake stop to your function. You can let it timeout every time.

Something like this:

```js
var folders = null;

//call this to start the process or set the property manually
function start() {
  folders = ['id-of-the-starting-folder'];
  work();
}

//set this to run on the trigger
function work() {
  if( folders == null )
    folders = ScriptProperties.getProperty('folders').split(',');

  while( folders.length > 0 ) {
    workOnFolder(folders[0]);
    folders.shift(); //remove the 1st element
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('folders', folders.join());
  }
  //remove the trigger here
}

function doFolderLater(folder) {
  folders.push(folder.getId());
}

function workOnFolder(id) {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(id);
  folder.getFolders().forEach(doFolderLater);
  folder.getFiles().forEach(workOnFile);
}

function workOnFile(file) {
  //do your thing
}
```

Comment: Nice Henrique, this algorithm hinges around the concept of first storing the list of folders (siblings at the current depth) to do later. I will need to use the paging methods instead of getFolders/Files though because if a single folder has N direct child files and processing N files takes longer than 6 minutes (expected sometimes as I have >million files and folders and growing over time). How could I do that - somehow also store the token from its folder keyed to a folder id?

Comment: Yes, I'd still have the array to save the folders, but also have another property to save the files page token of the "current" folder, which will always be `folders[0]`. Also, the looping and saving of this files pages would have to be inside workOnFolder itself. Not much more difficult than this. I'll take a look at this later and edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check in later.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu I am struggling with more or less the same but I do not have the list of folder names. I try to save the next token to hold on to my next starting point, but it seems impossible to JSON.Stringify this token, the Token object seems to be a black box. Any insights on this ?

Comment: @koma This answer is kind of outdated already, Google launched the DriveApp, which is a replacement for DocsList. But this is not possible on this new DriveApp either. A good "trick" would be to use a specific folder as "marker" that you've already processed a file/folder. On the new DriveApp you have advanced search parameters that allows to better search folders/files and filter out, for example, all that have a particular folder as parent (your marker).

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu Yes, found this open issue https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2834 by now. DocsList is marked experimental, so I considered this the newer API. DriveApp does not have a notion of Token to use for iteration.